# Is it possible to set time interval between adjacent operations in Batch API?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I need to send several thousands of e-mails via Amazon SES. As it turned out, Amazon SES can send no more that 14 e-mails per second. I can send to it no more than 14 e-mails per second - it's a requirement of Amazon SES.

I send e-mails to Amazon via Drupal Batch API. Could you clarify me, is it possible to set time interval between adjacent operation upon creating the batch command ?

That is, current batch command is sending 14 e-mails, then a time interval is appears before executing the next command.

Is it possible to realize it ?

Comment: Don't think the batch API has anything for that, but it would be as trivial as checking the remainder of current result no. / 14 == 0 and sleeping in the batch op

Comment: I would try to use background_process module and inject sleep() function in the process, does that make any sense?